# Custom attribute wrapping XmlAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I have the following code:

```
[MyAttribute(BindTo="Name")]
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
public String _Name { get; set; }
```

Would it be possible to wrap `XmlAttribute` to `MyAttribute` to produce the following code?

```
[MyAttribute(BindTo="Name", AttributeName="Name")]
public String _Name { get; set; }
```

If yes, how?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The reason why I want to do this is because all `MyAttribute` are `XMLAttribute` too and I want the `XmlSerializer` to recognize them.

Comment: Please explain the reason, why you want to do that. It is not possible without changing `MyAttribute`.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to have "MyAtrribute" be a sub class of XmlAttribute and create a AttributeName property which sets it to the parent.AttributeName?

Comment: The question is: Will this still be recognized by the XmlSerializer? I doubt it.

Comment: I am okay with changing MyAttribute. I just want to decrease the attributes, if possible. And yes, I want the XmlSerializer to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAttribute : XmlAttributeAttribute
{
    public String BindTo {get; set;}
}
```